# Compile Lua 5.3 Mingw64 MSys2

Tags: c++, windows, lua, mingw-w64

I have installed **mingw64** and **MSYS2** from the official site (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) following the instructions. Added bin folders to win7 **PATH** var. Everything seems to work. I run this command from **MSYS2**:

```
gcc --version
```

and it works.

Now I´m trying to install **Lua** 5.3 (lua-5.3.1.tar.gz from lua.org). I decompressed the file using WinRAR. From MSYS2, I go to my Lua directory

```
cd /e/Programming/Libs/lua-5.3.1/
```

then I run the make command

```
mingw32-make mingw
```

But it doesn´t work. I got this message...

```
cd src && E:/Programming/mingw64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make mingw
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/Programming/Libs/lua-5.3.1/src'
E:/Programming/mingw64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make "LUA_A=lua53.dll" "LUA_T=lua.exe" \
"AR=gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -o" "RANLIB=strip --strip-unneeded" \
"SYSCFLAGS=-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL" "SYSLIBS=" "SYSLDFLAGS=-s" lua.exe
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- =
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- g
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- u
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- 9
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- 9
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option -- a
E:\Programming\mingw64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: unrecognized option '--strip-unneeded SYSCFLAGS=-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL SYSLIBS= SYSLDFLAGS=-s lua.exe'
Usage: mingw32-make [options] [target] ...

This program built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>
makefile:116: recipe for target 'mingw' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [mingw] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/Programming/Libs/lua-5.3.1/src'
makefile:55: recipe for target 'mingw' failed
mingw32-make: *** [mingw] Error 2
```

I dont want to download Lua binaries, I want to compile it myself

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently your `make` is seeing the `gcc` flags. Please ask this in the Lua mailing list.

Comment: Or try running it in a normal cmd shell. The reason could be different escaping in the MSYS shell ...

Comment: Using normal cmd shell.. Same errors..

Comment: May I ask why you use mingw32? Is that suppose for 32 bits?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. This question is from 8 years ago. I'm not using Lua anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I looked at this page:

http://www.thijsschreijer.nl/blog/?p=863

What I saw was that I did not have c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin  in my path variable. I added it just after the MinGW\bin path and it worked fine then.